# Function validation of USB on ASIC

Tags: validation, post, embedded, usb, silicon

I am an embedded systems engineer and our company is planning for a USB 3.0( host and device )protocol compliance suite/ Post silicon validation covering functional test cases. Actually i have previously worked with functional validation of low speed peripherals like I2C,SPI developing bare metal(without any OS) test cases,running on a simple microcontroller. I am not sure whether i can do the same with USB,as i think the protocol by itself is complex.Does it require to develop test cases using OS or RTOS? Can the functional test cases be run on a uniprocessor system? I am aware linux kernel and U-BOOT has USB support.If it's better to use kernel,how the existing USB stack in kernel can be used to write test cases? Can anyone shed light on this ?

Comment: I think a forum focused on validation or USB is better than this website, as SO is focused on concrete problems with programming.

Answer (score 0):

USB 3.0 (particularly superspeed) is not a simple block, and validation of it covers the entire gamut of hardware and software specs, plus interoperability testing.  See http://www.usb.org/developers/compliance/

You really need to engage a professional services company with experience doing this if you're the person that's being relied upon for post silicon validation of this block, otherwise your company runs the risk of shipping a product that can't get the logo (or worse).  You should probably engage them prior to tape out so your company can lessen the chances of very expensive mistakes.  And I don't say this to insult you, but to make it plain to you that if you're asking about it stack overflow, you're not equipped to do the job in the near future.

BUT, when I did USB2.0 high speed certification for an ASIC, we had to have a functional stack on the device under test (our chip, which was an ARM with integrated USB PHY), and we ran a USB certification test on a windows pc, with a specific set of USB peripherals attached to it (the "golden tree"), plus we had to do eye diagrams, etc. to verify our waveforms were compliant.  We also did testing with a Mac, but that was more a marketing decision than a compliance issue.

Comment: Oh.. thanks a lot for your reply Russ Schultz .:) Ya..even i am aware that it's not an easy task and i am not equipped as of now.It's not strictly dead line bound.Your pointers are very useful for me.I shall do some homework and get back...Are there any forums or online tutorials for this ?